# How to animate HTML5 shapes using a spine curve

Tags: javascript, html, animation, transform, spline

I've made a program that creates parametric shapes (spheres, toruses, and cylinders) and performs matrix transformations on them to animate them in specific ways (e.g. translate(), rotate(), scale()). I now want to animate the shapes using splines which will serve to allow the shapes to move along smoother paths than with the transformations alone. I'm not exactly sure how to approach this with html5 and javascript, but based on my work up to this point, I would think that the approach would involve first calculating all of the points that lie along the spline curve (for x,y, and z), storing each point in a data structure, and then iterating over the data structure passing in each point to the translate() method.

I've looked at some resources on [B-Splines](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~david/Classes/CS430/Lectures/L-09_BSplines_NURBS.pdf) and [NURB's](http://www.mactech.com/articles/develop/issue_25/schneider.html) but sites like these generally seem either very theoretical and hard to translate to code, or they use specific api's in languages that I'm not using. What would be the best implementation (code wise) of this sort of spline animation in html5 and javascript?

Comment: check this out may be it can be off some help http://blog.visual.ly/creating-animations-and-transitions-with-d3-js/

Comment: @Cyril I was looking more for resources that can help with making splines from scratch without a library.